# PHPStorm changes group when saving file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

When editing a file with PHPStorm, the group is changed from `www-data` to my local user. I've added my local user to the `www-data` group, and if I edit the file with `gedit`/`vim`/etc. the group stays as `www-data`.

I suspect PHPStorm must be running as a different user, but when I check `ps`, it shows as my local user.  What would cause this program to alter the group of a file it's editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What causes this is most likely is that the original file is backed up by the editor and then the new file is written so it gets the current group id of the user. The editor would have to explicitly reset the group to the original group.

You could try to use `newgrp` to change the group of the user doing the editing before starting PHPStorm:

```
newgrp www-data
```

Comment: It looks like this is in fact the case.  PhpStorm has a feature called 'safe write' doing just this!  Thanks.

Comment: Or disable the "safe write" option as detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248933/deleting-modifying-file-contents-from-phpstorm-changes-group-of-the-file-in-lin